# What's the point of the :link pseudo-class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I understand `:link` allows to select unvisited elements, and I'm aware of the [LoVe-HAte trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/link-pseudo-classes-in-order/) to remember the order in which order to put the various link pseudo-classes. But in practice I always style my links like this:

```
a {
    /* common styles for all links, regardless of state */
    /* this includes unvisited links, and thus a:link */
}
a:visited {
    /* specific styles for visited links */
}
a:hover {}
a:active {}
```

Since a link is either visited or unvisited, this covers all possible cases, and I really don't understand what the `:link` pseudo-class adds to the table.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `a:link` selector lets you set the styles on `<a>` tags that actually link somewhere.

Bare `<a>` tags without an `href` attribute are traditionally used as markers in a document; setting the location to `document.html#foo` will jump you to wherever `<a id="foo">` is in the document. It is, after all, called an "anchor" tag for a reason.

Traditional HTML may look something like this:

```css
a {
    color: green;
}
a:link {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Navigation</h2>
<a href="#ch1">Chapter 1 (red :link)</a>

...

<h3><a id="ch1">Chapter 1 (green anchor)</a></h3>
<p>It was the best of times...</p>
```

Subsequent HTML standards let you use the `document.html#thing` syntax to jump to any element with the attribute `id="thing"`, but it wasn't always the case.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense, although (as you point out) it's not very useful anymore. Kind of a vestigial pseudo-class. :) Thanks.

Comment: In traditional HTML, named anchors use the name attribute instead. The id attribute, for all elements, is the more modern way of doing things.

Answer (score 4):

There might be some cases where you would like unvisited links to catch the attention of visitors, especially if it is an important one. Is it used a lot? I don't know, I haven't actually found the need to use it. I do the same as you as far as I remember.

But I guess in the end it is nice to have the option to be able to style those links separately than not to have it.

I guess one use case I can think of is a word cloud (like in blogs with tags) where you want unvisited links get a larger font than the rest.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the `:link` pseudo-class was just introduced for the sake of symmetry with `:visited`... I agree that it's nice to have that option, but you still could achieve the same thing using my method: style all links by default to be eye-catching, and then override that for `:visited` links. So all in all, the `:link` pseudo-class seems quite useless to me, which I find a bit surprising.

Answer (score 4):

The `:link` pseudo-class is used to select and style unvisited links in a page. It applies to links that have not yet been visited.

An element can be both :visited and :active so as the `:link` pseudo-class will have an effect.

`:active`, `:hover`, or `:visited` pseudo-classes override the style defined by the `:link` pseudo-class. For styling links properly, the `:link` rule should be placed before all other link-related rules (`:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:active`).